# Equivalent descriptions of axiom of regularity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The axiom of regularity is the following: If $x\neq\emptyset$, then $\exists y\in x$ such that $y\cap x=\emptyset$. I want to show that this equivalent to the following: There is no sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of sets such that $...\in y_{n+1}\in y_n\in...\in y_2\in y_1$.

My attempt: Assume the axiom of regularity. Let $x=\{y_1,...,y_n,...\}$ be a collection of sets with the property $...\in y_3\in y_2\in y_1$. Let $y\in x$. Then $y=y_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But then $y\in x$ and since $y_{n+1}\in y$, we note that $y\cap x=y_{n+1}\neq\emptyset$ (since $y_{n+2}\in y_{n+1}$). Giving a contradiction.

Conversely, suppose there is no sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of sets such that $...\in y_{n+1}\in y_n\in...\in y_2\in y_1$. Suppose the axiom of choice is false. So there is a non-empty set $x$ such that for **every** $y\in x$, we have $y\cap x\neq\emptyset$. Since $x$ is non-empty, let $y_1\in x$. Since $y_1\cap x\neq\emptyset$, let $y_2\in y_1\cap x$. So $y_2\in y_1$ and $y_2\in x$. $y_2\in y_1\implies$ we have $y_2\in y_1\in x$. $y_2\in x\implies y_2\cap x\neq\emptyset$, and so there exists a $y_3\in y_2\cap x$. We can repeat this procedure indefinitely, and we get $...\in y_{n+1}\in y_n\in...\in y_2\in y_1$ contrary to our assumption.

Does anyone see any problems? Thank you.